# AngularJS duplicated element for 1 second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have my login form that contains a box to display the error message

```
<div class="ui negative message" ng-if="vm.message != ''">
    <span ng-bind="vm.message"></span>
</div>
```

The message is set inside my controller

```
LoginService.checkUser(vm.credentials).then(function(res) {
    $rootScope.token = res.data.token;
    $state.go('home');
}, function(err) {
    vm.error = true;
    if(err.status == 401){
        vm.message = "Error !";
    }
});
```

My problem is that the `div` containing the message is shown 2 times during 1sec after clicking on the login button. Thus during 0.5/1 second I have 2 times the same `div` with the same message.

User cannot see what it says but he can see something blinking.

How can I avoid getting a blink ?

Comment: So this happens only on login error since that's the only time you're changing the message?

Comment: Yes there is no other place where I change the error message

Comment: read about ng-cloak

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo it works only when the application is loading which as I understood has nothing to do with the question since the blinking happens when the function is called when the DOM is already fully loaded.

Comment: @thepio You are right. All the page is loaded and it happens on button's click.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I already use ng-cloack on my body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the error was a little bit stupid and was in part of the code that I did not show.

The full login function is

```
    vm.error = false;
    if (vm.credentials.username == '' || vm.credentials.password == '') {
        vm.error = true;
        vm.message = "Required username+password";
        return;
    }
    vm.message = "" //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    LoginService.checkUser(vm.credentials).then(function(res) {
        $rootScope.token = res.data.token;
        $state.go('home');
    }, function(err) {
        vm.error = true;
        if(err.status == 401){
            vm.message = "Error";
        }
    });
```

I was editing the message to empty before setting it to the error.

I remove this line `vm.message = ""` and it is now working fine

Comment: Heh, this is why I asked if you are changing the message value anywhere else as my first question :P

Comment: I did not even see this line :D sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-if` doesn't work in your HTML, change it to be like this:

```
<div class="ui negative message" ng-if="vm.message">
  <span ng-bind="message"></span>
</div>
```

The statement `ng-if="vm.message != ''"` did not hide the element which causes the blinking. You can even declare `vm-message = null` in your controller when it's loaded just to make sure.

Comment: It is still blinking

Comment: Hmm...are you sure the Login service or the button click is not called twice by any chance? Could you put a console log on both of them an make sure they aren't called twice.

Comment: I posted the answer, anyway my ng-if was working and thank for the help